# How do I deploy a C++ application in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c++, deployment, visual-studio-2013, publish

I have made a C++ Console Application in Visual Studio 2013. I want to publish/deploy to allow it to run on my friend's computer. I don't see a *publish*  option anywhere like in VB 13! 
How can I make setup which can install my application on any computer as a .exe file allowing it to run at a single click?
Note: OS is Windows 7

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Comment: Do a release build and copy the exe. That's all you need to do.

Comment: That is not all you will need to do, @user. You'll also need to ensure that an appropriate version of the C runtime library is installed. You can't assume that.

Comment: @CodyGray You can use static linkage to include the C runtime library in the exe itself.

Comment: @user515430 your method doesn't seem to work... where exactly does the exe file appear?

Comment: @CodyGray i have downloaded the Installer, but could use some help... do you know anything that might help?

Comment: @SrujanPalkar The exe is in Project\Your-project-name\Release. Otherwise, use the search capabilities of your OS to find the exe. Hopefully you know its name :-)

Comment: @user515430 it doesn't seem to work... but using the installer did create the setup that i wanted... Thanks for your help! :)